# Android Studioでデバッグの際に値が表示されない

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

以前までAndroid Studioでデバッグすると、行ごとにアドレス値やnullなどが書いてある値が表示されていたのですが、どこを触ったのか突然消えてしまいました。元の状態への戻し方が分からず、困っています。どこを設定すればまたデバッグの際に行ごとの値が表示されるようになるでしょうか？すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。
Android Studioのバージョンは1.1 Beta4です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

すみません。質問の意図を取り違えていました。
「Show Variables in Editor」機能のことですね。

[image: エディタ内の、実行済みの各行右側に変数の値が表示される]

この機能をトグルするには、Debug ビューのツールバー > Settings > Show values in Editor を使えば良いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 値を見ることができるようになりました！
ありがとうございました^^

Answer (score 0):

私も時々同じ状況になりますが、ケーブルを挿し直して駄目なようなら、

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

としてみると治ります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
kill-server と start-server をしてみたのですが、デバッグでの値が表示されませんでした。。。

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 上で View が消えてしまっただけなら、

View > Tool Windows > Debug

で表示させることが出来ます。
通常はデバッグ実行すると自動的に表示されると思うので
これでは解決しないかもしれませんが..

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。一応デバッグのViewは表示されているのです。試しに一度Viewを消してもう一度再表示させてみたのですが、やはりデバッグの値は表示されませんでした。。。